# In SQL Server, are subqueries automatically optimized?

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

Please ignore the reasons why I wrote the query this way, that's not the subject of the question, as this is a hypothetical derived from a real world example.

I have a case where I need to retrieve records through pagination: only 9 records every page.

I have a subquery which retrieves all rows from the `users` table (> 10,000 rows), and in the enveloping query, I apply the pagination, like this:

```
select * 
from
    (select firstname, lastname, age
     from users)  -- returns > 10,000 rows
order by lastname asc
offset 0 rows fetch next 9 rows only
```

Now, again, please ignore why it's written this way, my question is more about understanding how SQL Server optimizes queries: does SQL Server actually run the subquery, and then return the entire resultset first, then filters it down to the first 9 rows, which of course impacts the performance negatively, OR, does it somehow optimize it so it never has to return the entire resultset, resulting in the same performance if there was no subquery?

I have re-written the query to be more direct, like below:

```
select firstname, lastname, age
from users
order by lastname asc
offset 0 rows fetch next 9 rows only
```

yet to my surprise, I didn't notice THAT much of an improvement in performance, which lead me to think maybe SQL Server does it's own optimization behind the scenes?

Does anyone have any clues?

Comment: That query isn't valid, you can't `OFFSET` without an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Questions about performance and general underlying functioning of the server cannot be answered without the execution plan, due to different table statistics and even sql server versions. Click the "Show actual execution plan" button, save the plan to xml, and use an online service like https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ to paste it and provide a link back. Then, we can tell you exactly the flow.

Comment: The optimizer optimizes queries as a whole. It is not guaranteed to run subqueries or common table expressions "first" and then operate on those results; in fact, most of the time it doesn't do that because it sees a straightforward approach that either can't be written as-is in T-SQL, or would be less readable. The actual results are still highly variable and depend on the specifics of the query.

Comment: @Larnu correct you are. Like I mentioned above, this is a hypothetical that is driven from a real world example, and the real world example has an order by clause.
I fixed it in the code

Comment: @JeroenMostert That makes sense. I think in this case, MSSQL seems to be optimizing it so it is not actually retrieving all 10,000 records for this operation.
But it would still be nice to get a confirmation that this is what's happening.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis Thanks. I will have to create a dummy DB and table to run this example, as the real world example is a huge an unecessarily complex query (that I'm in the process of attempting to optimize).  
So since the question is only about the subquery issue, I will try that for the above simplified query and post the results of the execution plan.

Comment: Then a query that isn't valid isn't hypothetical; it's simply wrong. I can tell you *exactly* how a query that contains invalid syntax will run: The parser will detect the invalid syntax and the query will not be run. No need to be hypothetical; this is a known. No need for optimisation here, you need to fix the syntax issue.

Comment: Then, per the others, you should learn about execution plans, how to get them, and how to read them. You will see that trivial subqueries of the form `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM T) <otherstuff>` will simply be folded back into `SELECT * FROM T <otherstuff>`. There are no guarantees (as in, things written in stone) about how the optimizer does its work, because it's big seething mass of heuristics in proprietary code, but the fact that it folds subqueries and CTEs back into one query and optimizes the whole is a well known fact established empirically.

Comment: @Larnu I'm not sure what you are on about, I already admitted that it was omitted by mistake from my example, and fixed it in the example. thank you for your feedback.

Comment: You didn't say that was an error (that you corrected), you said it was hypothetical, @beliha . That *suggested* that you omitted the `ORDER BY` by intention, and wanted to know how SQL Server behaved *if* it could ran the query. You have changed the code, yes, but the comment didn't suggest that, so i didn't check it again.

Comment: @Larnu no, I meant in the real world example (where this example is derived from) I have the order by clause, which is why I have no parser errors. But when I wrote this example above, I mistakenly ommitted the ORDER BY clause. 
That's what I meant by "this is a hypothetical". As in "don't get sidetracked with other things outside of the question itself"
And I started my answer with "correct you are", and ended it with "I fixed it in the code". Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL is a *descriptive* language, not a *procedural* language.  A SQL query *describes* the results being produced.  It does not specify HOW those results are calculated.

That is the function of the compiler and optimizer.  In fact, the code that is executed looks nothing like the original SQL statement.  Technically, it is called a DAG (directed acyclic graph).  And it uses a bunch of primitive operators that you would not recognize.  It is often difficult to figure out what in the original query matches to a particular operator.

When SQL Server executes a query, the entire query is optimized.  SQL Server has a good optimizer, so it is not fooled by subqueries.  You will probably find that the execution plan for the two queries is *exactly the same*.

Note that all databases work this way.  However, not all optimizers are equal.  So, if you use subqueries in MySQL (older versions) or MS Access, then you might find a noticeable performance difference.